# Issue combining When statements inside a Class

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, optimization

**How do I combine two Kotlin When statements when they are inside the Class?**
Is this where a case when statement would come into play?

When creating a flash card application, I I initially had the when statement working like this but it had to be copy and pasted underneath each buttons' OnClickListener (one counting up, and one counting down).

```
Val image = when (nextCard) {
    1 -> {
        num.text ="Piston Assembly"
        R.drawable.piston
    }
    2 -> {
        num.text = "Engine Oil"
        R.drawable.oil
    }
    3 -> {
        num.text = "Crankshaft"
        R.drawable.crank
    }
    4 -> {
        num.text = "Engine Strokes"
        R.drawable.fourstrokeone
    }
    5 -> {
        num.text = "Engine Block"
        R.drawable.block
    }
    6 -> {
        num.text = "Connecting Rod"
        R.drawable.conrod
    }
    7 -> {
        num.text ="Cylinder Head"
        R.drawable.head
    }
    8 -> {
        num.text = "Piston Rings"
        R.drawable.rings
    }
    9 -> {
        num.text = "Valves"
        R.drawable.valve
    }
    10 -> {
        num.text = "Camshaft"
        R.drawable.camshaft
    }
    else -> {
        num.text = "Engine"
        R.drawable.engine
    }
}
```

After reviewing the code to condense it and make it hopefully more efficient and readable, I moved the when statement into a class but was unable to get it to work properly without splitting up the When statements like this.

```
class CardDeck(val current_card:Int=0) {
    private val nextCard = current_card

    fun chosenImage():Int{return this.image}

    fun chosenText():String{return this.words}  

    private val image = when (nextCard) {
        1 -> piston
        2 -> oil
        3 -> crank
        4 -> fourstrokeone
        5 -> block
        6 -> conrod
        7 -> head
        8 -> rings
        9 -> valve
        10 -> camshaft
        else -> engine
    }

    private val words = when (nextCard) {
        1 -> "Piston Assembly"
        2 -> "Engine Oil"
        3 -> "Crankshaft"
        4 -> "Engine Strokes"
        5 -> "Engine Block"
        6 -> "Connecting Rod"
        7 -> "Cylinder Head"
        8 -> "Piston Rings"
        9 -> "Valves"
        10 ->"Camshaft"
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the mappings in a map and get the required values using the `nextCard` value

```
data class Image(val image: R.drawable, val words: String)
val map = mapOf(
    1 to Image( piston, "Piston Assembly"),
    2 to Image(oil, "Engine oil"))
    ... // rest of the mappings
)
val nextCard =  TODO()
val image = map[nextCard].image
val words = map[nextCard].words
```